# SQL Query does not print 0 on UNION

Tags: mysql, oracle11g

I am new to SQL queries and I am working on a query to print the `COUNT` of movies an actor has appeared in, including a total of `0` if they have not appeared in any movies.

I am getting all results as expected except if an actor has not appeared in any movies then they do not appear in the list.

Here is what I have so far -

```
SELECT a.actor_name, count(*) 
FROM ACTOR a 
JOIN CAST_MEMBER c ON (a.actor_name = c.actor_name) 
GROUP BY a.actor_name 

UNION 

SELECT c2.actor_name, 0 
FROM ACTOR a2 JOIN CAST_MEMBER c2 ON (a2.actor_name = c2.actor_name) 
WHERE a2.actor_name NOT IN 
( 
    SELECT a3.actor_name 
    FROM ACTOR a3 
    JOIN CAST_MEMBER c3 ON (a3.actor_name = c3.actor_name)
)
```

---

```
EXPECTED OUTPUT 

ACTOR_NAME                       COUNT(*)
-------------------------------------------------- ----------
Amy Adams                           1
Brad Pitt                           4
Christian Bale                      1
Jennifer Anitson                    0
Jennifer Lawrence                   2
Leonardo DiCaprio                   2
```

---

```
OUTPUT I HAVE

ACTOR_NAME                       COUNT(*)
-------------------------------------------------- ----------
Amy Adams                           1
Brad Pitt                           4
Christian Bale                      1
Jennifer Lawrence                   2
Leonardo DiCaprio                   2
```

---

I would really appreciate it if someone could guide me in the right direction.

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: could you give a sqlfiddle?

Comment: @Leandro is that sqlfiddle? still new so not sure if thats what you are asking for.

Comment: here: http://sqlfiddle.com/ 
So you/we can try a solution

Comment: Sqlfiddle has been a bit ill for a couple of days. Sadly I know of no good alternatives.

Comment: Not sure how sqlfiddle will help. Never used it.

Comment: Can someone tell me why this question deserves a downvote?

Comment: I have edited your question to format your question a little more clearly :) I am not sure why you were downvoted (I often wish there was a way to know, too!) but in future if you format your code as readably as possible and make sure the question is as clear as possible, with the code you have tried, expected result and actual result, then hopefully you will get more upvotes and not be downvoted again.

Comment: @Eilidh Thank you for editing and will make of that in future. Thank you

Comment: @Mani No problem at all! Tell me what you want your output to look like? I will try to help with an answer.

Comment: @Eilidh , I will post the expected output in a sec, editing it as of now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.actor_name, count(*) 
FROM ACTOR a 
LEFT JOIN CAST_MEMBER c ON (a.actor_name = c.actor_name) 
GROUP BY a.actor_name;
```

You need to use LEFT OUTER JOIN in order to show all rows from table ACTOR.

> An outer join is a join that displays data from the same rows an inner
>   join does, but also adds data from rows that don’t necessarily have
>   matches in all the tables that are joined together. There are three
>   types of outer joins—LEFT, RIGHT, and FULL.

Comment: ^ This looks to me like it should work. Mani, I'm not sure why you have the second part of your query? Try it and let us know if it works?

Comment: @Mani Have you removed the second half of your query, including and after the `UNION`? It is not necessary. 

What did you expect the second half of your query to do?

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER WITHOUT THE UNION

```
ACTOR_NAME                       COUNT(*)
-------------------------------------------------- ----------
Amy Adams                           1
Brad Pitt                           4
Christian Bale                      1
Jennifer Aniston                    1
Jennifer Lawrence                   2
Leonardo DiCaprio                   2
```

ANSWER WITH THE UNION

```
ACTOR_NAME                       COUNT(*)
-------------------------------------------------- ----------
Amy Adams                           1
Brad Pitt                           4
Christian Bale                      1
Jennifer Aniston                    0
Jennifer Lawrence                   2
Leonardo DiCaprio                   2
```

My error was on the joins, Now I have a better understanding of them.